# Translate table in pure js

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I've made a simple table in HTML, CSS and [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/), and I want to change the dates that are in the cells. (translate text)

```html
<table class="table table-striped" id="TabelPret">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">id</th>
            <th scope="col">service</th>
            <th scope="col">price(Euro)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>consulting</td>
            <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>RECONSULT</td>
            <td>15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>1 procedur/30 min</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>                                            
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now for JS, i try to select the table then to add new rows and colums:

```
var array = [
    ["a1", "b1", "c1"],
    ["a2", "b1", "c1"],
    ["a3", "b1", "c1"],
    ["a4", "b1", "c1"],
    ["a5", "b1", "c1"],
    ["a6", "b1", "c1"],
    ["a7", "b1", "c1"]
];
```

That array will be the new cells so (`a1` is translate for id, `b1` is translate for consulting, `c1` is translate for price...etc)

```
table = document.getElementById("TabelPret");
for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; i < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
    table.rows[i].innerHTML = array[i][j];
  }
}
```

This code doesn't work for me, is there another option ? Only in  pure JavaScript, the table will be static.

Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Is that your real HTML? I noticed that your `<tr>` and `</tr>` tags don't match up properly. Was that a typo in your post or your actual code?

Comment: yes is my code i have more <tr> tags and i reduce them for only few, i don't see the last </tr> when i delete his body sorry for that

Comment: You spelled length wrong too

Comment: ok thx for that typo :( i change it but still doesnt change :(

Comment: You're also missing out a `</tr>` for your first row.

Comment: thx Jacob for that, I will edit the post. Thx for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the array instead and use `document.createElement` to create rows and cells to append to the `tbody`.

```js
const tbody = document.querySelector('table > tbody');
var array = [
      ["a1", "b1", "c1"],
      ["a2", "b1", "c1"],
      ["a3", "b1", "c1"],
      ["a4", "b1", "c1"],
      ["a5", "b1", "c1"],
      ["a6", "b1", "c1"],
      ["a7", "b1", "c1"],
    ];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  const row = document.createElement('tr');
  for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
    const cell = document.createElement('td');
    cell.textContent = array[i][j];
    row.appendChild(cell);
  }
  tbody.appendChild(row);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-striped" id="TabelPret">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">id</th>
      <th scope="col">service</th>
      <th scope="col">price(Euro)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>                            
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thx man this is good :) it works and it is more simple and less text thx again

Comment: @andrei0292 No problem.

Comment: This works, but  i have 3 language, when i swamp betwen them all cells are copied from one to another. exemple : at the start i have 3 rows in french, then i swamp to english and i have 6 rows (3 french and 3 english), after i swamp in french again and i have 9 rows (3 french and 3 english and again 3 from french) i try to solve this tomorow. thx for your help again :)

Comment: @andrei0292 You may want to ask a new question if you are unable to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your loop to reference each cell and assign from your 2d array:

```
table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML = array[i][j];
```

Comment: i try this and change only the <th></th>, not the <td></td> thx for this it really help me :)